# Do Android ListView rows have a height limit?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I was just wondering, if I have a normal listview and I add some component to its rows, say, another list, and set its visibility to gone, then populate the inner list later and make it visible, will it show and grow the parent row as necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will grow the Cell, the Cell Layout itself is typically wrap_content so it will grow. They are several DevBytes from Googles Android Team specific for that Topic.

Check this Episode:

[DevBytes: ListView Expanding Cells Animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwE61B56pVQ)

Answer (score 0):

For the literal meaning of the title:

Yes, the max value in theory is INT_MAX, because it is defined in [ViewGroup.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

Another thing to mention is that due to a bug in [View.MeasureSpec](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html) on prior platforms, the maximum valid value can be smaller.

---

For the intended question:

Yes, it will re-layout the UI, because the layout hierachy will be re-measured when such things changes, throough calls to [View.requestLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29) and then [View.onMeasure()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure%28int,%20int%29), which normally gets overriden in subclasses of View.

So If you set the layout parameter to `wrap_content`, it should grow or shrink automatically.

And the DevBytes mentioned by Michele is also worth watching.

Another thing to mention is that normally you should not nest `ListView`s, for that the implementation makes this impossible (see [ListView.onMeasure()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/ListView.java#1173)), because this is not the intention of `ListView`, which features in view recycling. (However long time ago I worked around this limit with a dirty hack :P)

For the elegant approach, you may want to use `LinearLayout`, or you may take a look at [LinearListView](https://github.com/frankiesardo/LinearListView)